# Github API returns CORS error when using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to download the latest release of a specific **private** repository. I am able to gather information by using this GET request:

```js
const handleDownload = async () => {
    const token = "{Very secret token not for StackOverflow}";
    const owner = {company};
    
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/releases/latest`,
      {
        //mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
      }
    );

    const log = await response.json();
    console.log(log);
}
```

This call returns some data, including the 'zipball_url' property, where i think my download comes from. However, if i try to make a request to this URL (including my token), i am getting a nasty CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://codeload.github.com/{company}/{reponame}/legacy.zip/refs/tags/1.1.7?token={secret token}' (redirected from 'https://api.github.com/repos/{company}/{reponame}/zipball/1.1.7') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The Github API Docs are not helping me very much. Can someone explain me how to fix this?

Comment: Do you publicly provide your _"very secret token"_ in the source code of your website?

Comment: Unless your repo is private, you shouldn't need any authorisation

Comment: @Phil my repo is private, as you can read in my explanation.

Comment: @jabaa No i don't, this is just a development example. In production i will, of course, take safety measures.

Comment: What safety measures? Every user can read your token in the dev tools. Your browser has to send it as clear text and users can read it in the network tab.

Comment: This is not really in the scope of my question so i don't know why this is important to get into right now.

Comment: Because the question doesn't make sense as long as this isn't solved. One reason the API doesn't send CORS headers is to avoid people publicly providing their _"very secure tokens"_. The solution to the whole problem depends on the solution to the problem in my first comment. You could use a proxy that adds CORS headers, but that would mean every user gets access to your token. You could use your own proxy and add CORS headers and your token there.

Comment: Thats fair. So because i am sending my token in a public accessible header, the GitHub Api won't allow it? In the answer down here said i could use the `zipball_url` directly. This gives me a JSON response which says 'Not found', do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: An API, that expects a secret token, usually doesn't allow direct access from a browser. It makes sense that you can't access a private repository without any credentials (though I would expect 403 instead of 404). I recommend using a proxy, that adds the token and CORS headers (or make the repository public).

Answer (score 2):

The `zipball_url` simply redirects to the `codeload.github.com` sub-domain and Github doesn't allow public CORS access to that.

If you're wanting the user to download the file, just use the `zipball_url` directly in a `<a download>` element

```jsx
const [ zipUrl, setZipUrl ] = useState(null)

const downloadRef = useRef(null)

const getLatestRelease = async () => {
  // this is greatly simplified with no error handling for brevity  
  const res = await fetch(yourGithubUrl)
  return (await res.json()).zipball_url
}

useEffect(() => {
  getLatestRelease().then(setZipUrl)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  // trigger download
  if (zipUrl) {
    downloadRef.current.click()
  }
}, [ zipUrl ])

return zipUrl && (
  <a
    download
    ref={downloadRef}
    href={zipUrl}
  >
    Download
  </a>
)
```

Another option is to use `window.open(zipball_url)` but that will open a new tab.

Comment: I tried this approach already. This redirects the browser to a page with a json response like this: `{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive"
}`.

I think this is because my repo is private.

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same error:
{   "message": "Not Found",   "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive" }

and it got resolved when i register in the below url, it got resolved:

To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXXXXXX   to authenticate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31895190)